# Trouble loading neural network on GPU using theano

Tags: python, gpu, theano

I am using an amazon EC2 server with a nvidia K80 gpu, for running a neural network using Theano and Lasagne. When I try to train the network I get the following error:

**MemoryError: Error allocating 5060952064 bytes of device memory (CNMEM_STATUS_OUT_OF_MEMORY).**

The K-80 should have 12 GB memory, and I have CNMeM enable with 95% memory as printed below:

**Using gpu device 0: Tesla K80 (CNMeM is enabled with initial size: 95.0% of memory, cuDNN 5105)**

Any hints as to what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Full error message can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/dULi4nmd

Comment: I ran into similar problems - did you find a solution in the meantime? For me it worked when I set CNMeM to only 1% of the memory, which is very weird.

Comment: Did not find a solution, but found the cause of the problem. The memory on the GPU is contiguous so if I did multiple runs then the memory from an earlier run would be allocated on the GPU and thus not available. The "solution" was to drop the kernel operating on the GPU thereby releasing the used memory

Comment: Okay, by dropping the kernel you mean killing the respective process on the GPU?

Comment: Yes! Just shutting down what ever process is using the resources, I was using python, killing the python kernel made the memory free again